# Class xxx does not contain a public constructor needed to autobuild when xxx become a Tapestry Service

Tags: resteasy, tapestry, tynamo

I'm discovering the wonderful integration work made by Tynamo's team between Tapestry and Resteasy .

I'm trying to activate Liveclass Reloading on webservices. As per doc says :

### Documentation

> The only thing you need to do to enable live class reloading for your
>   REST services is to bind them as regular Tapestry IoC services and
>   contribute them to javax.ws.rs.core.Application.class. Read more about
>   how service implementation reloading works in:
>   http://tapestry.apache.org/reload.html
>
> Here is an example from the tapestry-resteasy test suite.

```java
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder)
{
    binder.bind(ReloadableEchoResource.class, ReloadableEchoResourceImpl.class);
}

@Contribute(javax.ws.rs.core.Application.class)
public static void configureRestResources(Configuration<Object> singletons, ReloadableEchoResource reloadableEchoResource)
{
    singletons.add(reloadableEchoResource);
}
```

### My Own Work

This is exactly what I'm doing (well ... hmmm at least I believe that it is ;D):

#### My binding

```java
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder)
{
    binder.bind(PushMessageService.class, GCMPushMessageServiceImpl.class);
    binder.bind(UserService.class, HibernateUserServiceImpl.class);
    binder.bind(IUserResource.class, UserResourceImpl.class);

}

/**
 * Contributions to the RESTeasy main Application, insert all your RESTeasy singletons services here.
 */
@Contribute(javax.ws.rs.core.Application.class)
public static void configureRestResources(Configuration<Object> singletons, IUserResource userResource)
{
    singletons.add(userResource);
}
```

#### My Interface

```java
@Path("/user")
public interface IUserResource {

    /**
     * Lecture de tous les utilisateurs
     * 
     * @return une List des utilisateurs existants
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public abstract List<User> getAllDomains();
```

### Error

But when I start my app, I obtain this message :

```java
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /user. Reason:

Exception constructing service 'ResteasyRequestFilter': Error building service proxy for service 'Application' (at org.tynamo.resteasy.Application(Collection) (at Application.java:14) via org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at ResteasyModule.java:31)): Error invoking service contribution method org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyModule.javaxWsRsCoreApplication(Configuration, ObjectLocator, ResteasyPackageManager, ClassNameLocator): Class com.sopragroup.ecommerce.mobile.rest.IUserResource does not contain a public constructor needed to autobuild.

Caused by:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'ResteasyRequestFilter': Error building service proxy for service 'Application' (at org.tynamo.resteasy.Application(Collection) (at Application.java:14) via org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at ResteasyModule.java:31)): Error invoking service contribution method org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyModule.javaxWsRsCoreApplication(Configuration, ObjectLocator, ResteasyPackageManager, ClassNameLocator): Class com.sopragroup.ecommerce.mobile.rest.IUserResource does not contain a public constructor needed to autobuild.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
```

It's quite like the autobinding don't works (indeed I do think it is).
Obviously, when I try to without creating an interface and binding, it works like a charm.

Can someone give me a clue ?

Comment: Can you share UserResourceImpl. I suspect it does not have a public constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that *tapestry-resteasy* is trying to autobuild *IUserResource* because it's in the "rest" package.

Here is a very important documentation line that you may have missed:

> One more thing: DO NOT put this service in the autodiscovery package.

This is an important line and it was somehow hidden in the docs so I added a warning to make it more visible for future users: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/diffpagesbyversion.action?pageId=151847035&selectedPageVersions=24&selectedPageVersions=23

Comment: Wow ! The master himself (again) :). Thanks for your reply. Indeed, I saw it, but didn't understand the underlying mechanism until you caught my attention. You mean that this service should not be in rest package (neither in services) ?. Rest one is only intented to auto binding and discovering ? I will try it in a few hours !